# convert Json array key value to js array

Tags: javascript, json

```
$AllSorts = array();
$AllSorts[] = array('type'=>'العدد الكلي','num'=>$allSize);

$AllSorts[] = array('type'=>'عدد الطلاب','num'=>$studentSize);

$AllSorts[] = array('type'=>'عدد الأساتذة','num'=>$tchSize);

$AllSorts[] = array('type'=>'عدد المدراء','num'=>$managerSize);

$AllSorts[] = array('type'=>'عدد مراقبي الدوام','num'=>$atsSize);

$AllSorts[] = array('type'=>'عدد مراقبي الحافلات','num'=>$bgrSize);

$AllSorts[] = array('type'=>'عدد مراقبي الرسوم','num'=>$fgrSize);


$JsonData = json_encode($AllSorts);
echo $JsonData;
```

this is the php code to get thw json date

```
var jsonData = '';
    
$.get('../Functions/Ajax/GetSortingData.php?id='+schoolId, function(data){
            jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(jsonData);
    
       });
var labels = [];
var datas = [];
for(const obj of jsonData){
   labels.push(obj.type);
   datas.push(obj.num);
}
console.log(datas);
```

and this is the javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the array of objects.

```js
var arr = [
  {type: "العدد الكلي", num: 14},
  {type: "عدد الطلاب", num: 8},
  {type: "عدد الأساتذة", num: 2},
  {type: "عدد المدراء", num: 1},
  {type: "عدد مراقبي الدوام", num: 1},
  {type: "عدد مراقبي الحافلات", num: 1},
  {type: "عدد مراقبي الرسوم", num: 1}
];
var labels = [];
var datas = [];
for(const obj of arr){
  labels.push(obj.type);
  datas.push(obj.num);
}
console.log("Labels", labels);
console.log("Datas", datas);
```

For your particular case, you need to be looping over the array in the callback for the AJAX call, as AJAX is asynchronous.

```
$.get('../Functions/Ajax/GetSortingData.php?id='+schoolId, function(data){
            jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(jsonData);
            var labels = [];
            var datas = [];
            for(const obj of jsonData){
               labels.push(obj.type);
               datas.push(obj.num);
            }
            console.log(datas);
       });
```

Comment: @R4EGroup What do you mean? The array is empty after?

Comment: no error just give 0 size of the labels and datas array

Comment: @R4EGroup What exactly does your JSON data look like? Is it an array of objects?

Comment: @R4EGroup Are you trying to parse the JSON as a string?

Comment: my json is a string i get from php ajax then i do json.parse to it

Comment: yes i parse it  in javascript after i get from php server

Comment: @R4EGroup So it looks exactly like it does in the question?

Comment: @R4EGroup How do you use `JSON.parse` on it when it isn't valid JSON?

Comment: i create  a jsonData array

Comment: var jsonData = '';     then  i get the date from php  and parse the json string date to the javascript array that called jsonData

Comment: @R4EGroup Does the array not look like the array in my answer?

Comment: it look the same in the browser console

Comment: @R4EGroup Could you please provide a reproducible code example of the problem?

Comment: man !!!! it works thank you very much .... but can u explain me why it work like that not like the last way

Comment: @R4EGroup No problem.

Comment: @R4EGroup The problem with your original approach was that you were trying to access the JSON data before it was received from the server. Since AJAX is asynchronous, it does not halt code execution and thus your code to get the labels and data was executed before the response was returned from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const array = [{
    type: "العدد الكلي",
    num: 14
  },
  //.snip
]

const type = array.map(i => i['type'])
console.log(type)

const num = array.map(i => i['num'])
console.log(num)
```